# Using ReadLine input for controlling which item i want to use in an array and get their item numbers?

Tags: c#, arrays

Let's say I have 2 arrays I've already created in my program (array "a" and array "b") they both has the same amount of items. They have different values but they complete each other in the number order. What I want to do is when I enter the name of an item in array "a" it should give me the number of that item, then use that number to call the name of an item in array b. For giving an example of what I have in my mind please check this code:

Let's say array "file" has the items "abc", "cde", "fgh" and array "directory has the items "123", "456", "789"

```
string[] file = new [] { "abc", "cde", "fgh" };
string[] directory = new [] { "123", "456", "789" };
string typed;
typed = Console.ReadLine();

if (typed == file[(name of one of the items in array "file" for example "abc")])
```

because "abc" is the first item in array "file", I need some command to change it to a item number, in this case [0]

```
{
    int given number = file[number of the item we entered]
    Process.Start(directory[given number]+file[the same number that has been converted]);
}
```

**Edit:** I am so sorry but i made a little mistake when im asking the question (i mean i asked the right question but forgot the part of it) the part that i typed "*if (typed == file[(name of one of the items in array "file" for example "abc")])*" i dont know how to make the array got readen by the input that user entered can you please help me with that too?

Comment: So you want `.IndexOf(...)`? Are all the items in the array unique?

Comment: I recommend you use a dictionary. For each file item store its value and on readline you just return the value based on this key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Array.IndexOf() method returns the index at which a specific item occurs in an array. If the item does not occur in the array at all, then it returns -1 instead. You can make use of this method to meet your requirement, something like this:

```
string typed = Console.ReadLine();
string[] file = {"abc", "cde", "fgh"};
int result = Array.IndexOf(file, typed);

//result of IndexOf will be 0 or higher if it found a matching string in the array
if (result >= 0)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Your input value " + typed + " exists in the array at index " + result.toString());
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Your input did not match anything");
}
```

See [the documentation for Array.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx)

N.B. This works properly only if all the values in your array are unique.

Comment: Im sorry to bother, but i added a few lines to my question could you please help me again.

Comment: @aGoodFellow `Array.IndexOf(file, typed)`, perhaps? My example used a hard-coded value to search for, you simply have to substitute it with your input variable.

Comment: if i get you wrong please tell me but that what i did and it did not work:
`string nameofprogram = Array.IndexOf(file,typed).ToString(); `

                 `if (typed == nameofprogram)`
                 `{`
                    `Console.WriteLine("it works!");`
                 `}`

Comment: no because Array.IndexOf returns a number i.e. 0, as I mentioned above, whereas `typed` will be a string like "abc", so you can't compare those two things with an `if` statement. If you use your visual studio debugger you'll be able to stop on that line using a breakpoint and see what values are about to be compared. You asked how to get the numeric index of what the user has input (if any), which is what Array.IndexOf gives. It makes no logical sense to then try and compare it to the text.Because of what Array.IndexOf returns you already know if the text matches anything in the array or not

Comment: Im so sorry im just making this more and more confusing, yes the part that i wanted to get the numbers is right however in the "if" part what i want to get is the items name in the array like i said in the part that starts with bold font, because i dont know how to do that either however when i asked the question i didnt make it clear enough that i wanted that, its completely my fault. so its like the program gets the string input from the user then it checks if that string input is in that array or not, then converts that input into a number if it exists, at least that what i wanted to achive

Comment: " in the "if" part what i want to get is the items name in the array"...the item's name is what the user already input, no? Why do you need to get it again? You already know it. All you need to do is test whether the user's input exists in the array. You already do that by using Array.IndexOf. If it exists, IndexOf will return its index (i.e. 0 or higher), if it doesn't exist it will return -1, as per the documentation I linked you to. I've updated the answer to try and help you a bit.

Comment: HALLELUJAH! THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem. If the answer has helped you please remember to mark it as accepted (click on the tick next to the question so it turns green) - thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it better to store in a dictionary?

```
var directories = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

So the user types "abc", it looks up and returns directories["abc"].

However, if you absolutely insist on the array approach you could do it like this:

```
var index = file.IndexOf(directories, "abc");
```

... then grab the corresponding item in the directories array - directories[index];

Comment: Im sorry to bother, but i added a few lines to my question could you please help me again.